# How to show that a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix can be written using its eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ be a real symmetric positive semidefinite square matrix (finite) and ${\lambda _k}$, ${{\mathbf{q}}_k}$ corresponding eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Show that $B = \sum\limits_k {{\lambda _k}{{\mathbf{q}}_k}{\mathbf{q}}_k^T}$.

My attempt: First, since $B$ is real and symmetric, we can choose it's eigenvectors ${{\mathbf{q}}_k}$ to be normed and mutually orthogonal. We have

$B{{\mathbf{q}}_i} = {\lambda _i}{{\mathbf{q}}_i} = \sum\limits_k {{\lambda _k}{{\mathbf{q}}_k}\underbrace {{\mathbf{q}}_k^T{{\mathbf{q}}_i}}_{{\delta _{ki}}}} $

so they are equal on each of the eigensubspaces of $B$.

How can I see that they are equal everywhere?

EDIT: Ok, so it seems that all answers rely on the fact that ${{{\mathbf{q}}_k}}$ can form a basis (it's enough for me to see that they span the whole space, I know that they're orthogonal, and hence linearly independent). How to prove that?

Comment: Isn't every vector a linear combination of eigenvectors of $B$?

Comment: Well, if I could show that they span the whole space, then yes

Comment: I guess the real question is whether or not you have the (finite real) spectral theorem at your disposal, that is, whether or not you know that a real self-adjoint square matrix is real-orthogonally diagonalisable, and hence yields an orthonormal basis for the relevant inner product space consisting of eigenvectors of that matrix.

Comment: Found it, thanks

Comment: I would have done it already, but none of the answers were complete, just restatements of what I've originally written in my question. Branimir's comment was the most helpful step towards finding the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As many have stated, $B$ does not need to be positive semidefinite.

What you're looking for is probably the [spectral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Hermitian_maps_and_Hermitian_matrices). The proof is on Wikipedia too. It relies on the following facts:

1. You can always find one eigenvalue-eigenvector pair. You may want to work with $\mathbb C$ instead of $\mathbb R$ here.
2. The eigenvalue is real. This justifies the extension to $\mathbb C$ made in 1. You also get that the eigenvector has real components.
3. The orthogonal complement of the subspace spanned by the eigenvector is invariant.

Item 1 follows almost immediately from the fundamental theorem of algebra. You'll need to use the fact that $B$ is hermitian (real symmetric) to prove 2 and 3. Then induction finishes your proof.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that already, as I've said

Answer (score 1):

It's not important that $B$ is positive semi-definite. If it's real and symmetric then it has an eigenvalue/eigenvector decomposition $B = X \Lambda X^{-1}$ where the columns of $X$ are eigenvectors of $B$ and $\Lambda$ is diagonal with the eigenvalues of $B$ on its diagonal. Since $B$ is real and symmetric, it is always possible to choose the basis of eigenvectors to be orthonormal (as you mentioned). In this case the matrix $X$ is orthogonal and therefore $X^{-1} = X^T$. Let's rename it $Q$. Thus you obtain $B = Q \Lambda Q^T$. Expanding this expression is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $B$ is a $n\times n$ symmetric (hence diagonalizable) matrix.

On the one hand $Bq_1=\lambda_ 1q_1$.

On the other hand $$(\lambda_ 1 q_1q_1^T + \cdots + \lambda _n q_nq_n^T)q_1=\lambda_ 1 q_1(q_1^Tq_1) + \cdots + \lambda _n q_n(q_n^Tq_1) $$

Now since $q_1$ is orthogonal to $\displaystyle q_2,\dots ,q_n$, only $\lambda_ 1 q_1$ will prevail, because $q_1q_1^T=1$ and $q_i^Tq_1=0$, for all $i\in \{1,\dots , n\} \backslash \{1 \}$.

Now recall that $Bq_1=\lambda_ 1q_1$. So you have $Bq_1=(\lambda_ 1 q_1q_1^T + \cdots + \lambda _n q_nq_n^T)q_1$.

Similarly you can get $\displaystyle Bq_i=(\lambda_ 1 q_1q_1^T + \cdots + \lambda _n q_nq_n^T)q_i$, for all $i\in \{1,\dots , n\}$.

Let us write $C=(\lambda_ 1 q_1q_1^T + \cdots + \lambda _n q_nq_n^T)$.

Since $B$ is symmetric, it follows that $\{q_1,\dots ,q_n\}$ is a basis $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So you have $Bv=Cv$, for all vectors $v$ of a basis. This implies that $B=C$ (need help proving this?), which is what you want.

Sorry for changing the notation slightly, It's easier for me this way.

You don't need $B$ to be positive semidefinite.

Comment: towards the top of your answer you need to assume that $B$ is diagonalizable, i.e., that it is possible to choose $\{q_1, \ldots, q_n\}$ orthonormal. Then it's clearly a basis.

Comment: @Dominique What do you mean I need to assume $B$ is diagonalizable? It is diagonalizable because it's symmetric.

Comment: @"Git Gud" Your answer starts with no assumption on $B$. I was just saying it would be best to state that $B$ is diagonalizable (because it's real and symmetric) from the onset.